# Custom GCM broadcast reciever not being used on a couple of devices, but works on others

Tags: java, android, google-cloud-messaging

I creating an app that's using GCM to receive notifications from our servers, am using Google's gcm.jar, and have a customGCMIntentService class handling it. My problem is that only one handset is actually getting a response (or more likely routing the response correctly) from GCM when calling `GCMRegistrar.register()`.

What I'm seeing is that the GCMRegistrar (from the gcm library) is correctly setting my custom broadcast receiver as the retry receiver on the nexus 3 phone, the only one that works, but not on the others. This makes me believe that I might be getting a response from GCM but its not being processed on the three other phones (detail below).

```
GCMRegistrar Setting the name of retry receiver class to <My_application_package>.CustomGCMBroadcastReceiver
```

All of them have a data connection that allows communication with GCM, all have an active gmail account on them ( all of them have the playstore working ). I've also run Google's GCM demo on them all without a problem.

**The registration code**:

```
 //This is almost identical to how Google's GCM demo does it.
 private void registerOnGCM(){
    checkNotNull(SERVER_URL, "SERVER_URL"); //What it says on the tin
    checkNotNull(SENDER_ID, "SENDER_ID");
    // Make sure the device has the proper dependencies.
    GCMRegistrar.checkDevice(this);
    // Make sure the manifest was properly set - comment out this line
    // while developing the app, then uncomment it when it's ready.
    GCMRegistrar.checkManifest(this);
    /*
    registerReceiver(mHandleMessageReceiver,
            new IntentFilter(HANDLE_MESSAGE));
    */
    final String regId = GCMRegistrar.getRegistrationId(getApplicationContext());
    if (regId.equals("")) {
        // Automatically registers application on startup.
        GCMRegistrar.register(getApplicationContext(), SENDER_ID);
    } 
    else {
        // Device is already registered on GCM, check server.
        if (GCMRegistrar.isRegisteredOnServer(getApplicationContext())) {
            // Skips registration.
            Log.i(TAG, "Already registered");
        } else {
            // Try to register again, but not in the UI thread.
            // It's also necessary to cancel the thread onDestroy(),
            // hence the use of AsyncTask instead of a raw thread.
            final Context context = this;
            mRegisterTask = new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>() {
            @Override
            protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
                boolean registered = ServerUtilities.register(context, regId);

                if (!registered) {
                    GCMRegistrar.unregister(context);
                }
                return null;
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
                mRegisterTask = null;
            }

        };
        mRegisterTask.execute(null, null, null);
    }
}
```

The code for CustomGCMBroadcastReceiver doesn't matter, nor does the GCMIntentService, since neither of them is ever call'd. Problem isn't with them.

**Devices I'm testing on**:

- HTC Desire GSM running CyanogenMod 7
- Google nexus 3 running Android 4.1.1 (Application works on this one)
- Motorola T910 running Android 4.0.1
- Samsung Galaxy mini running Android 4.2.6

**Manifest**:

```
<uses-sdk  android:minSdkVersion="8" android:targetSdkVersion="16" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

<!-- App has permission to read/write files on sd card. Used for RSS document -->
<uses-permission android:name = "android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name = "android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>

<!-- GCM connects to Google Services. -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

<!-- GCM requires a Google account. -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />

<!-- Keeps the processor from sleeping when a message is received. -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />

<permission
    android:name="<My_package_name>.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature" />
<uses-permission
    android:name="<My_package_name>.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />

<!-- This app has permission to register and receive data message. -->
<uses-permission
    android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />



<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
    android:label="@string/app_name">
    <activity
        android:name="<My_package_name>.MasterActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">
    </activity>

    <activity   android:name="<My_package_name>.WebActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <!--
      BroadcastReceiver that will receive intents from GCM
      services and handle them to the custom IntentService.

      The com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND permission is necessary
      so only GCM services can send data messages for the app.
    -->
    <receiver
        android:name="<My_package_name>.CustomGCMBroadcastReceiver"
        android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
        <intent-filter>
            <!-- Receives the actual messages. -->
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
            <!-- Receives the registration id. -->
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />
            <category android:name="<My_package_name>" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

    <!--
      Application-specific subclass of GCMBaseIntentService that will
      handle received messages.

      By default, it must be named .GCMIntentService, unless the
      application uses a custom BroadcastReceiver that redefines its name.
    -->
    <service    android:name="<My_package_name>.GCMIntentService"
                android:enabled="true"/>
 </application>
```

Might be something I've forgotten to add. Let me know.

All ideas are welcomed.

-MrDresden

Comment: Is <My_package_name> really the name of your packages or did you just replace it by this generic message?

Comment: @Qkyrie '<','>' are invalid chars in package name.

Comment: exactly why I questioned his naming. Before jumping to conclusions, I was looking at the obvious things. You never know the level of competence of mrDresden

Comment: Yeah sorry about that harsh reply, had been a rather long and difficult day at the office. Not that's any excuse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well it seems to have fixed it self by only cleaning, and rebuilding and then deploying that to those other devices.

Why removing all traces from all phones, then running in debug mode on them didn't work, except on one phone I have no idea.

Comment: I have the exact same problem, you fixes it just by cleaning and re-installing the app?

Comment: Well for me, removing the app from the device, cleaning the project, rebuilding, and running on the device worked.